C# VS 2022 : Executing py file thru IronPython
I am trying to execute one python (.py) file from C# code in VS 2022, on Windows 11.
I have added IronPython package to the project.
This python file have the functionality to draw a diagram as code, using this Python library: mingrammer/diagrams
Note: Execution of .py file is working fine in command prompt, outside Visual Studio 2022.
My issue is in VS 2022 code.
Also, all components are installed on my machine as follows:

public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    doPython();

    return;
}

private static void doPython()
{
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
    // This path enable Diagram Library.. thats is working FINE.
    paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Win11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages");
    // This line resolve : "contextvars" library
    paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Win11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib");
    
    // Trying to resolve the library path named : "_contextvars" ,, Not yet
    paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Win11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\__pycache__");

    paths.Add(@"C:\Users\Win11\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\libs");
    engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);
    
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\diagrams\test.py");
}

Exception Details as follows:
IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: 'No module named '_contextvars'':

How to let IronPython access this module and proceed with the execution?
